# example of build_query function?

Tags: functions, query

I have this resource: (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/build_query), but it does not give full example.

I have this URL:

mypage/?page_id=87

and this array:

```
array('name' => 'me')
```

So, I need to add the array to the end of the URL. I know the build_query function will add the proper markup ( & ), but how do I connect the function to the URL. e.g.- How do I use the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`build_query()` converts an array into a string to be used in an URL. You can pass an array or an object:

```
$test1 = array (
    'foo'   => 'bar',
    'hello' => 'world'
);
$query1 = build_query( $test1 );
print "<pre>$query1</pre>"; // foo=bar&hello=world

$test2 = array (
    'foo'   => 'bar',
    'hello' => 'world',
    'one'  => array( 1, 2 ),
    'two'  => array(
        'a' => 3,
        'b' => 4
    )
);
$query2 = build_query( $test2 );
print "<pre>$query2</pre>"; // foo=bar&hello=world&deep%5Ba%5D=1&deep%5Bb%5D=2

$test3 = new stdClass;
$test3->foo = 'bar';
$test3->arr = array( 5, 6, 'red' );
$query3 = build_query( $test3 );
print "<pre>$query3</pre>"; // foo=bar&arr%5B0%5D=5&arr%5B1%5D=6&arr%5B2%5D=red
```

To get the current URL you can use something like this:

```
$url = set_url_scheme(
        'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
    );
```

Now you *could* use `build_query()` to append your custom array values to the URL, but you can make that easier with `add_query_arg()`:

```
$custom = array( 'name' => 'me' );
$url    = add_query_arg( $custom, $url );
```

`add_query_arg()` will look for existing parameters in the URL and make sure they don’t get lost or interfere with the `$custom` values. If there are duplicate entries in both, `$custom` will overwrite existing parameters.

`build_query()` is used in `add_query_arg()` too, but for no obvious reasons you cannot pass an object to `add_query_arg()` like you can use it in `build_query()`. Objects are dropped silently.

Comment: OK, I see how that works. My situation is this: The url I have is based on a query, i.e.- my-page/?page_id=87. So, I need the add_query_arg to add to that. However, this is not yielding any results. Also, my URL is generated from a link. So, when the link is clicked the URL is called and that is when I need to pass the extra values ( to another page ).